# Button, checkbox/radio and input field design inconsistency in daisyui

Tags: tailwind-css, daisyui

I'm having design inconsistency issue for button, radio, checkbox, and input in daisyUI component. i'm using prefix to avoid conflict, as per suggestion by the tailwind css & daisy ui documentation.

here in my code -

> `tw-` is a tailwind css prefix and `du-` is a daisyUi prefix.

Note : daisy ui suggests to use combination of tailwind and daisyui prefix for its classes to avoid conflict with existing CSS. [read about it here in the docs](https://daisyui.com/docs/config/#prefix)

Even after following everything as per docs, I'm having below issue. Please let me know how to fix it. Thank you for the suggestions.

##### issue 1

- design issue in button. Check the code and screenshot.

```html
<button class="tw-du-btn tw-du-btn-outline ">Default</button>
<button class="tw-du-btn tw-du-btn-outline tw-du-btn-primary ">Primary</button>
<button class="tw-du-btn tw-du-btn-outline tw-du-btn-secondary ">Secondary</button>
<button class="tw-du-btn tw-du-btn-outline tw-du-btn-accent ">Accent</button>
```

[image]

##### temporary fix for issue 1

- added `tw-border-solid` class to fix the design inconsistency.

```html
<button class="tw-du-btn tw-du-btn-outline tw-border-solid">Default</button>
<button class="tw-du-btn tw-du-btn-outline tw-du-btn-primary tw-border-solid">Primary</button>
<button class="tw-du-btn tw-du-btn-outline tw-du-btn-secondary tw-border-solid">Secondary</button>
<button class="tw-du-btn tw-du-btn-outline tw-du-btn-accent tw-border-solid">Accent</button>
```

[image]

##### issue 2

- design issue in input field. Check the code and screenshot.

```html
<label class="tw-du-input tw-du-input-bordered tw-border-solid tw-flex tw-items-center tw-gap-2">
        <input type="text" class="tw-du-grow" placeholder="Search"> 
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" class="tw-w-4 tw-h-4 tw-opacity-70">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.965 11.026a5 5 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.755 2.754a.75.75 0 1 1-1.06 1.06l-2.755-2.754ZM10.5 7a3.5 3.5 0 1 1-7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 7 0Z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </svg>
    </label>
```

[image]

##### temporary fix for issue 2

- added `tw-border-none` class to hide the border.

```html
<label class="tw-du-input tw-du-input-bordered tw-border-solid tw-flex tw-items-center tw-gap-2">
        <input type="text" class="tw-du-grow tw-border-none" placeholder="Search"> 
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" class="tw-w-4 tw-h-4 tw-opacity-70">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.965 11.026a5 5 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.755 2.754a.75.75 0 1 1-1.06 1.06l-2.755-2.754ZM10.5 7a3.5 3.5 0 1 1-7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 7 0Z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </svg>
    </label>
```

[image]

Please suggest me how to fix the issue and what are the steps can be taken to adress the issue. below is my tailwind config-

````js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require("daisyui")
  ],
  daisyui: {
    themes: false, // false: only light + dark | true: all themes | array: specific themes like this ["light", "dark", "cupcake"]
    darkTheme: "dark", // name of one of the included themes for dark mode
    base: true, // applies background color and foreground color for root element by default
    styled: true, // include daisyUI colors and design decisions for all components
    utils: true, // adds responsive and modifier utility classes
    prefix: "du-", // prefix for daisyUI classnames (components, modifiers and responsive class names. Not colors, now class name for daisyui component will be tw-du-CLASSNAME(ie. tw-du-alert))
    logs: true, // Shows info about daisyUI version and used config in the console when building your CSS
    themeRoot: ":root", // The element that receives theme color CSS variables
  },
  prefix: 'tw-',
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}```
````